# Flutter plugin onActivityResult never called

Tags: flutter

I wrote a flutter plugin.

I need to detect the result in "onActivityResult", but "onActivityResult" never called.

Here's the part of my code.

```
class TappayflutterpluginPlugin: FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler, ActivityAware, PluginRegistry.ActivityResultListener {
constructor(context: Context) {
    this.context = context
  }

  override fun onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
    val channel = MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.binaryMessenger, "tappayflutterplugin")
    plugin = TappayflutterpluginPlugin(flutterPluginBinding.applicationContext)
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(plugin)
  }

  override fun onAttachedToActivity(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {
    Log.d("onAttachedToActivity", "onAttachedToActivity")
    binding.addActivityResultListener(this)
    plugin.activity = binding.activity
  }

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?): Boolean {
    Log.d("onActivityResult", "onActivityResult")
    when (requestCode) {
      LOAD_PAYMENT_DATA_REQUEST_CODE -> when (resultCode) {
        Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
          Log.d("RESULT_OK", data.toString())
          paymentData = data?.let { PaymentData.getFromIntent(it) };
        }
        Activity.RESULT_CANCELED -> {
          Log.d("RESULT_CANCELED", data.toString())
        }
        AutoResolveHelper.RESULT_ERROR -> {
          val status: Status? = AutoResolveHelper.getStatusFromIntent(data)
          if (status != null) {
            Log.d("RESULT_ERROR", "AutoResolveHelper.RESULT_ERROR : " + status.statusCode.toString() + " , message = " + status.statusMessage)
          }
        }
        else -> {
        }
      }
      else -> {
      }
    }
    return false
  }
}
```

I never saw the log of Log.d("onActivityResult", "onActivityResult") in Logcat.

Please help me.

Please please please.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you fount the solution for this

Comment: Did you find solution? I'm stuck their too

Comment: Still working on it

Comment: what is the value of LOAD_PAYMENT_DATA_REQUEST_CODE

Comment: Did anyone found a solution to it?